# How can I grab the width and height for a currentTarget in jquery?

Tags: jquery, events, resize, height, width

I'm trying to get the width and height of target when I click on it. event.currentTarget.width or event.currentTarget.width() (same for height) is not working. Any ideas on how to obtain the current targets width and height?

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use the jQuery methods you need to wrap the elements, e.g.:

```
$(event.currentTarget).width()
```

Otherwise you're stuck with using whatever DOM properties your browser supports, e.g..

```
event.currentTarget.offsetWidth
```